# Runtime binding to items in ListView.ItemTemplate

Tags: winrt-xaml, win-universal-app

I'm trying to bind an item inside a ListView.ItemTemplate's DataTemplate. This ListView is in a Grid, as in below:

```
    <Grid x:Name="catPageGrid">
    <Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
        <TransitionCollection>
            <EntranceThemeTransition />
        </TransitionCollection>
    </Grid.ChildrenTransitions>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--  Title Panel  -->
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Margin="19,0,0,0">
        <TextBlock x:Uid="Header"
                   Margin="0,12,0,0"
                   Style="{ThemeResource TitleTextBlockStyle}"
                   Text="category page" />
        <TextBlock Margin="0,-6.5,0,26.5"
                   CharacterSpacing="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemCharacterSpacing}"
                   Style="{ThemeResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}"
                   Text="{Binding}"
                   TextWrapping="NoWrap" />
    </StackPanel>

    <ListView x:Name="lvAmenityItem"
              Grid.Row="1"
              Margin="19,0,0,0"
              AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemListView"
              AutomationProperties.Name="Items In Group"
              IsItemClickEnabled="True"
              IsSwipeEnabled="false"
              ItemClick="ItemView_ItemClick"
              ItemsSource="{Binding}"
              SelectionMode="None"
              TabIndex="1">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid x:Name="grAmenityItem">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Border Width="79"
                            Height="79"
                            Margin="0,9.5,0,0"
                            Background="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                        <Image AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding}"
                               Source="{Binding}"
                               Stretch="UniformToFill" />
                    </Border>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1"
                                Margin="14.5,0,0,0"
                                VerticalAlignment="Top">
                        <TextBlock Style="{ThemeResource ListViewItemTextBlockStyle}" Text="{Binding}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

I used run time binding on the Grid:

```
    private void NavigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e)
    {
        var group = TestDataSource.GetAmenityGroup((string)e.NavigationParameter);
        catPageGrid.DataContext = group;

        //lvAmenityItem.DataContext = TestDataSource.GetAmenityItem((string)e.NavigationParameter);
    }
```

My problem is that I do not see the Grid with items after running.

I did this from the default Hub project template. I successfully binded in the same way to a Hub (to display the "first-level" information (i.e. AmenityGroup has AmenityItem(s)))

Am I doing something wrong here? Or can I not do it this way?

Thanks for your time :D

**EDIT:**

The code below only displays one item... as a start

```
Binding binding = new Binding() { Source = group.AmenityItems };
lvAmenityItem.SetBinding(ListView.DataContextProperty, binding);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay adding the Binding has done the trick

Just changed the Text binding to:

Where `Name` is a variable in the entity class returned in `group`.